# Jsoup connection to the link

Tags: java, jsp, jsoup

I want to parse links using Jsoup. It works normal, but when i pass as parameter link which look like "http://translate.google.com" (contains more than 1 dot) error is generated.

```
public class HtmlProcessor {

    public String[] getLinks(String url) throws IOException {

        Vector <String> hrefs = new Vector <String> ();

        try {

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect( url ).get();
            Elements links = doc.getElementsByTag("a");


            for (Element link : links) {

                hrefs.add(  link.attr( "href" ) );
            }
        } catch (ConnectException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

        return hrefs.toArray( new String [hrefs.size()] );      
    }
}
```

Comment: Please could you show some code?

Answer (score 0):

I tried going into http://translate.google.com and came out with a user agent error. Try this; it fixed the problem for me:

```
Document doc = Jsoup
        .connect( url )
        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/17.0 Firefox/17.0")
        .get();
```

Comment: Good to hear :) If you like it, please choose it as the best answer!